# How to make my localhost-server accessible for others on my WiFi

Tags: apache, localhost, sharing

I am currently on a mac using the pre-installed Apache server.

Now I need to cross-browser test some websites, and therefore I need to access my pages on some other computers. How can I make my localhost-sites accessible for other computers on my WiFi (without uploading to another server)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um... it's not working already?  It should be if you're using the default configuration.  You can access it by punching in the IP address of your dev server from another machine.

Comment: How can I check what my ip of this server is? I am pretty sure i have tested it a while ago (but now I have forgotten the IP) ..

Comment: go to a terminal, type in "ipconfig".

Comment: Well - found it now - and you were right, it was working.. Leave a reply :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache server's default configuration should allow other computers (even ones not on your local network) to access whatever it's serving up.

You can access your server from another machine by using the IP address of your server.  You can find the IP address of your server by finding a console (this works in Windows and Mac machines) and typing in "ipconfig".  (For linux machines, it's "ifconfig".)

Comment: "ipconfig" doesn't work for me on mac. It needs more commands/arguments. Type "ifconfig" in mac Terminal. And this has other methods that could be helpful for other users http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Mac